# WordPress $wpdb->query() does not return

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

After successfully executing two SQL DROP TABLE statements using `$wpdb->query()`, `$wpdb->query()` never returns from the third call. Below is the sample PHP code and the lines from the debug.log. I have been unable to find any documentation either here or at wordpress.org where someone else has reported a similar issue.

If I insert a DROP VIEW IF EXISTS statement before the third DROP TABLE, the DROP VIEW IF EXISTS executes and returns and when the third DROP TABLE is called `$wpdb->query()` never returns.

If I insert a second DROP VIEW IF EXISTS statement before the third DROP TABLE, both DROP VIEW IF EXISTS execute and return and when the third DROP TABLE is called `$wpdb->query()` never returns.

I have rearranged the DROP TABLE statements. It makes no difference which one is the third DROP TABLE.

If I execute one DROP TABLE IF EXISTS containing all three table names, it works fine.

```
$table_name1 = $wpdb->prefix . "Codes";
$table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . "Phrases";
$table_name3 = $wpdb->prefix . "Exceptions";
$SQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name1, $table_name2, $table_name3;";
$wpdb->query($SQL);
```

Dropping three tables in one statement is a satisfactory workaround but I am curious about why when I execute two DROP TABLE statements, a third one hangs. Have you seen this behavior before? Do you know why this occurs? Is it remedied on a newer software version?

This is the software suite I am to use in this engagement:
WAMP Server:

- Apache 2.4.23
- MySQL 5.7.14
- PHP 7.0.10
- WordPress 5.0.3

Sample code:

```
function Drop_Tables() {
    global $wpdb;
error_log("begin");
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "Codes";
    $SQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name;";
    $wpdb->query($SQL);
    $xresult=$wpdb->last_error; 
    if ($xresult) {
        error_log($xresult);
    }
error_log("After Drop Table Codes");
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "Phrases";
    $SQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name;";
    $wpdb->query($SQL);
    $xresult=$wpdb->last_error; 
    if ($xresult) {
        error_log($xresult);
    }
error_log("After Drop Table Phrases");
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "Exceptions";
    $SQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name;";
error_log("Before query()");
    $wpdb->query($SQL);
error_log("After query()");
    $xresult=$wpdb->last_error; 
    if ($xresult) {
        error_log($xresult);
    }
error_log("After Drop Table Exceptions");
}
```

From debug.log:

```
[19-Feb-2019 13:16:54 UTC] begin

[19-Feb-2019 13:16:54 UTC] After Drop Table Codes

[19-Feb-2019 13:16:54 UTC] After Drop Table Phrases

[19-Feb-2019 13:16:54 UTC] Before query()
```

Comment: What exactly does "hang" mean? Does it trigger the maximum execution time limit? Is there any more error message given? Does the process exit with an exception?

Comment: It never returns from the call. I have let it sit there for five minutes and it never returns to execute the next step in the PHP code. There are no error messages. The process does not throw an exception.